# How can I wait for two jQuery triggers in $.one method?

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

Consider following codes:

```
$(window).one(['clientSideDbIsReady','appIsDeployed'],function(){
    // some other codes
});

/* when client side db is ready: */ $(window).trigger('clientSideDbIsReady')

/* when application cache is ready: */ $(window).trigger('appIsDeployed')
```

How can I perform something like this ?

Note that caching is being performed by `applicationCache`, and client side db initialization is based on indexedDb internal operations, these operations are async so the execution of triggers is not ordered and fixed.

Is there any meaningful and maintainable code for this goal?

Extra notes:

I've managed to perform this by using jQuery promises and `Q.whenAll` method of Q JS.
But I want to use something like `$(window).one` which is much easier for development purposes.

Comment: what is clientSideDbIsReady and appIsDeployed??

Comment: This is not important, I trigger clientSideDbIsReady when my indexed db is initialized and its indexes are ready, and I call appIsDeployed when html 5 manifest cache is in cached state. How can I wait for both of them in one 'jQuery.one' method instead of developing much more codes.

Comment: are they variables?? if yes then this is not valid syntax.

Comment: `'jQuery.one'`...I have not seen anywhere in jQuery, where you found it?

Comment: @Jai I mean $(window).one http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @Jai Try the documentation. Binds an event once.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar This syntax is working well, but for one trigger

Comment: @Alex that is `.one` but OP mentioned `jQuery.one` which not there.